# Spring AOP pointcut is not triggered on an Object's method call when it is available inside list

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring5

I have a spring boot application with the couple of classes, configuration class and aspect as below. The below example is to illustrate the issue I face.

I have office class which has list of printers as dependency that is been created using external property file configuration. I would like to execute an aspect whenever Printer.getFilename method is been called. It is not triggering the aspect If I 
have list of Printers but It works when I have single Printer object without list.

```java
package com.example

public class Office {
   private final List<Printer> printersList;

   public Office(Printer printersList){
     this.printersList = printersList;
   }

   public void printFiles(){
      for(Printer printer: printersList)
        printer.getFileName();
   }
}
```

```java
package com.example

public class Printer {
  private deviceId;

  public String getFileName(){
     return "fileName";
  }
}
```

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration{
  @Bean
  public Office office(){
    List<Printer> printerList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Adding to the list based on printer id based on some external property file configuration
    printerList.add(new Printer());
    printerList.add(new Printer());
    return new Office(printerList);
  }
}
```

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class PrinterFileNameAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.Printer.getFileName())")
    private void getFileNameJp() {}

    @Around("getFileNameJp()")
    public String returnFileName(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
        return "Modified File Name";
    }
}
```

I find that the list of beans are not registered with the Spring container. Hence I modified the configuration class to register the bean

```java
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfiguration{
  @Autowired
  private GenericWebApplicationContext context;

  @Bean
  public Office office(){
    List<Printer> printerList = new ArrayList<>();
    // Adding to the list based on printer id
    Printer colorPrinter = new Printer();
    context.registerBean("colorPrinter", Printer.class, () -> colorPrinter);
    printerList.add(colorPrinter);
    Printer specialPrinter = new Printer();
    context.registerBean("specialPrinter", Printer.class, () -> specialPrinter);
    printerList.add(specialPrinter);
    return new Office(printerList);
  }
}
```

The above configuration changes doesn't help. I think I miss something in the fundamentals of spring aop. I want to implement the spring aop with the list of Printer since I can't change the list generation logic (The list generation logic is complex one and has to be dynamic).

Comment: You ought to make your around advice method public.

Comment: @kriegaex Sorry it was a type. I modified to public now

Comment: Why don't you just make `Printer` a `@Component` and let Spring take care of detecting your components via `@ComponentScan` instead of manually creating beans? Spring AOP does not work with classes which are not Spring beans/components. That can only be done with full AspectJ, but here it is not necessary. You ought to read the Spring AOP manual. It would be better than trial & error.

Comment: @kriegaex The point here is, I can't make Printer as component because it is been constructed dynamically based on property and the printers would vary based on property. If it is a predefined component spring will take care. My question here is how can I get the aspect working for dynamically generated beans

Comment: Okay, I understand. Anyway, your code is just pseudo code, can you provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For example, `this.printer = printer;` does not make any sense if `printer` is a list.

Comment: @kriegaex Modified the code. Kindly let me know if it is not working

Comment: I am not a Spring user, just an AOP aspect, but I know a little bit about Spring AOP. I think I am having an idea now. Let me copy, paste and run your code locally in order to verify my theory. It should be quite simple, but I need to check first.

Comment: One more question: Where does method `registerBean()` come from? I cannot find this in class `GenericWebApplicationContext`. Is it pseudo code again?

Comment: Please ignore that piece of code. It was trial and error code

Comment: Ah, `registerBean()` is Spring 5, my sample project was Spring 4.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213532/discussion-between-hurix-and-kriegaex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding an alternative answer because you seem to keen to learn how to use the new method `GenericApplicationContext.registerBean(..)` introduced in Spring 5. As I am not a Spring user, I also wanted to find out what that is about and came up with this solution.

Again, I am providing full class definitions. They are similar, but slightly different from my first answer. Specifically, `Printer` is no longer a prototype-scoped `@Component` but a POJO. I still left `Office` to be a singleton component for convenience, though. If you also need multiple instances there, you can always adjust the code according to your needs.

Now what is important and fixes your problem is this: After registering beans programmatically, you ought to acquire them from the application context via `getBean()` and not just add the manually created POJO instances to your printer list. Only if you get beans from the application context Spring takes care of also creating AOP proxies where necessary.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

public class Printer {
  private String deviceId;

  public Printer(String deviceId) {
    this.deviceId = deviceId;
  }

  public String getFileName() {
    return deviceId + ".pdf";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class Office {
  private final List<Printer> printersList = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addPrinter(Printer printer) {
    printersList.add(printer);
  }

  public void printFiles() {
    for (Printer printer : printersList)
      System.out.println(printer.getFileName());
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class PrinterFileNameAspect {
  // Package name is optional if aspect is in same name as Printer
  @Pointcut("execution(* de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740.Printer.getFileName())")
  private void getFileNameJp() {}

  @Around("getFileNameJp()")
  public String returnFileName(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    return "modified_" + pjp.proceed();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import java.util.stream.Stream;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class)) {
      // If you want to get rid of the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation, add this:
      // appContext.scan(Application.class.getPackage().getName());
      Office office = appContext.getBean(Office.class);
      Stream
        .of("colorPrinter", "specialPrinter")
        .forEach(deviceID -> {
          appContext.registerBean(deviceID, Printer.class, () -> new Printer(deviceID));
          office.addPrinter(appContext.getBean(deviceID, Printer.class));
        });
      office.printFiles();
    }
  }
}
```

The console log looks like this (shortened):

```
(...)
18:20:54.169 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'office'
18:20:54.177 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'colorPrinter'
18:20:54.178 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'specialPrinter'
colorPrinter.pdf
specialPrinter.pdf
(...)
```

Comment: we can avoid `office.addPrinter(appContext.getBean(deviceID, Printer.class));` and autowire the list of printers to `Office` lazily.  `@Autowired @Lazy private List<Printer> printersList` . [@Lazy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html) annotation reference

Comment: I am sure you are right and I appreciate the hint. I am the AOP guy, not the Spring guy. Coming up with Spring solutions is more or less trial & error for me, I am mostly concerned with getting the aspect questions answered. The rest I justt do because I like puzzles. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about this simple solution based on prototype scoped beans?

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class Printer {
  public String getFileName() {
    return "fileName";
  }

  public void configureIndividually(String whatever) {
    System.out.println("printer being configured individually: " + whatever);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class Office {
  private final List<Printer> printersList = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addPrinter(Printer printer) {
    printersList.add(printer);
  }

  public void printFiles() {
    for (Printer printer : printersList)
      System.out.println(printer.getFileName());
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class PrinterFileNameAspect {
  // Package name is optional if aspect is in same name as Printer
  @Pointcut("execution(* de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740.Printer.getFileName())")
  private void getFileNameJp() {}

  @Around("getFileNameJp()")
  public String returnFileName(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) {
    return "modified file name";
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q61661740;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) {
    Printer colorPrinter = appContext.getBean(Printer.class);
    colorPrinter.configureIndividually("my color config");
    Printer specialPrinter = appContext.getBean(Printer.class);
    specialPrinter.configureIndividually("my special config");

    Office office = appContext.getBean(Office.class);
    office.addPrinter(colorPrinter);
    office.addPrinter(specialPrinter);
    office.printFiles();
  }
}
```

Now you can let the container take care of generating bean instances, but you can still configure them individually. I don't see why you have to manually register the beans in this case.

The console log would be:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.8.RELEASE)

2020-05-10 15:52:24.817  INFO 10404 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q61661740.Application         : Starting Application on Xander-Ultrabook with PID 10404 (C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground\target\classes started by alexa in C:\Users\alexa\Documents\java-src\spring-aop-playground)
2020-05-10 15:52:24.821  INFO 10404 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q61661740.Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-10 15:52:25.895  INFO 10404 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-10 15:52:25.918  INFO 10404 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17ms. Found 0 repository interfaces.
2020-05-10 15:52:26.454  INFO 10404 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$377fd151] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-10 15:52:27.148  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-05-10 15:52:27.189  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-10 15:52:27.190  INFO 10404 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.24]
2020-05-10 15:52:27.375  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-10 15:52:27.376  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2486 ms
2020-05-10 15:52:27.681  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-10 15:52:28.005  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-10 15:52:28.007  INFO 10404 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q61661740.Application         : Started Application in 3.735 seconds (JVM running for 5.395)
printer being configured individually: my color config
printer being configured individually: my special config
modified file name
modified file name
2020-05-10 15:52:28.135  INFO 10404 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the package that contains `Printer` class to the SpringBoot application class and declare these within `@SpringBootApplication`

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class PrinterAspect
{
    @Around( "getFileNameJp()" )
    private String returnFileName( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) throws Throwable
    {
        return "Modified File Name"; // This will always return this name
    }
}
```

And finally, make enable the `AspectJAutoproxy` for the application

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.example.*" )
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy( proxyTargetClass = true )
public class Application
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run( Application.class, args );
    }
}
```

You also have missed the `@Component` in `Printer` and `Office` classes. So in conclusion, your `Office` class should look like,

```
@Component
public class Office
{
    private final List<Printer> printer;

    public Office( List<Printer> printer )
    {
        this.printer = printer;
    }
    public void printFiles()
    {
        // my code logic ...
        // Demo logic
        for( Printer printer1 : printer )
        {
            System.out.println( printer1.getFileName() );
        }
        // my code logic ...
    }
}
```

And the printer class should look like

```
@Component
public class Printer
{
    private int deviceId;
    private String fileName;

    public String getFileName()
    {
        // my code logic here ...
        fileName = String.valueOf( System.nanoTime() ); // demo logic
        return fileName;
    }
}
```

And the usage should look like,

```
@Autowired
private Office office;

@GetMapping( "/demo" )
public List<String> demo()
{
    office.printFiles();
    return fileNames(); // To be implemented
}
```

Comment: It doesn't help @klaus

Comment: @Hurix  tried this code injecting to a test rest endpoint and it worked. I have updated my answer with full code, hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works with component annotation. I can't have printer as a component because I construct the bean based on some property. `@configuration` is responsible for creating beans

Comment: Actually I think it should work if you make `Printer` a prototype-scoped bean, i.e. a new instance will be created each time you ask the application context for a bean, see [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes#prototype). Just create your printers via `getBean()` instead of direct constructor calls, then your aspect can intercept them. Making the `List<Printer>` a bean like you tried will not make any of the list's elements a bean, so no surprise here that this does not help you.

Comment: @kriegaex It is not about prototype. I need 3 or more printers based on properties and that should be singleton. Each printer would have different functionalities. I understand that I need to register the bean to spring container. My question is how can I register these bean to context and get the aspect working. I have tried to register but aspect not triggered for this